# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. while inserting data using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
select @sql='select * from application.dbo.'+@TableName1+''+char(13)+char(10)+'except'+char(13)+char(10)+'select * from '+'application_check'+'.dbo.'+@TableName1+''
exec sp_executesql  @sql


IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..##table') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##table
select @sql1='select * into ##table from '+ @TableName1+' where 1=2'

exec sp_executesql @sql1

insert into ##table 
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: and whats the question? can we have some background as to what youre trying to do?

Comment: it seems you don't have the same number/type of fields in `##table` and in your query's return... just compare both.

Comment: it should be `+'  except  '+` not `+'except'+` and please try to PRINT your query then you self will fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

you are removing the table ##table with the command DROP TABLE ##table so you cant select or even insert in it

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be fine.  It is creating a global temporary table with the names of columns and then inserting them.

So, really the only problem can be some difference in the tables in the different parts of the statement.  The table could be modified between the statements, but that is unlikely.

Your two SQL statements reference these tables:

```
from application.dbo.'+@TableName1

from '+ @TableName1+'
```

The only relevant difference I seee is `application_check.dbo.@TableName1` versus `@TableName1`.

So, I think you are not in the `application_check` database.  The database you are in has a table with the same name, and the columns are different.

By the way, I would write the first statement as:

```
select @sql = '
select *
from application.dbo.' + @TableName1+ + '
except
select *
from application_check.dbo.'+@TableName1
'
```

You don't need to explicitly put CR/LF into a string as characters.  You can just include new lines.

Comment: but i am facing the problem while inserting the data into the table at
insert into ##table 
exec sp_executesql @sql.

I even cross checked,  both the DB's have same number of columns

Comment: @shivanagesh . . . The same *number* of columns does not mean that the *types* are compatible.